# no of balls required to be taken so that 'k' balls are identical

Tags: combinatorics

If a bag contains $R$ red balls, $G$ green balls, and $B$ blue balls, how many balls should be taken out so that it has $k$ similar balls in the worst scenario?

**NOTE:** $R,G$ and $B$ may or may not be equal and $k \leq \max(R,G,B)$

Comment: It seems that your question is not quite related to probability and there is an answer about the worst scenario based on the pigeonhole principle. Instead if you are asking about that happen with at least $1 - \alpha$ probability, then you will need some computation about the multi-hypergeometric pmf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume $R \geq G \geq B$.

Then if $k \leq B$, your answer is $3k-2$ because if $3k-2$ balls are drawn then at least $k$ balls must be of the same color.

If $G \geq k > B$, then the answer will be $2k-1+B$, because if you draw $2k-2+B$ balls, then either you drew all the blue balls or you did not. Suppose you drew all the blue balls, then the remaining  $2k-1$ balls are green or red, out which at least $k$ are green or $k$ are blue. If you didn't draw all the blue balls, then more than $2k-1$ green or red balls were drawn, leading to the same conclusion.

If $R \geq k > G$, then the answer will be $k+G+B$, since suppose you drew all the green and blue balls, then the remaining $k$ must be red, and if you did not draw all the green or all the blue balls, then more red balls would have been drawn, leading to the same conclusion.

If $k>R$, then $k$ balls of the same color can't be drawn at all.

Comment: Maybe in the first case it should be 3k-1 and not 3k-2 balls as if R=G=B=3 and k=2 we require 5 (3k-1)balls and not 4 (3k-2)balls

Comment: @ShivanshuKantPrasad  The number $3k - 2$ is correct.  If you have four balls, even if you have one of each color after three balls have been selected, when you select the fourth ball, you will obtain a second ball of the same color as one that has already been selected.  More generally, the worst case scenario is that after $3k - 3 = 3(k - 1)$ selections, you have $k - 1$ balls of each color.  Once you select the $(3k - 2)$nd ball, you must have $k$ of the same color.